# How to use a json response in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, json

I have a simple method

```
 def country_list

    @countries = User.find(:all).map(&:country).uniq

    render :json => @countries

  end
```

if the path to it is `country_list_path`, how can I use the response as a list for autocomplete source for example, or just displaying?

If I put anywhere `country_list_path` I will get the url and not the response

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the JSON data directly, you should put `User.find(:all).map(&:country).uniq.to_json` instead of an URL that retrieves that data.